# Record a video for Allure in Playwright

Tags: playwright, allure

How can I record a video and it will be attached to allure like trace or screenshot?

```
 use: {

    actionTimeout: 0,
    trace: 'on',
    screenshot: 'on',
    viewport: {width:1920, height: 1080},
    video: 'on',
  },
```

that's what I have in playwright.config.ts and video is only one what is NOT working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-record-video), you have to specify the `dir` property of `recordVideo` context option. Otherwise videos are not recorded. Thus, your configuration file should look like this:

```
use = {
  actionTimeout: 0,
  trace: 'on',
  screenshot: 'on',
  viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
  video: 'on',
  contextOptions: {
    recordVideo: {
      dir: './output' // Or wherever you want the videos to be saved.
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you can specify the record video directory [on page level](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/api/class-browser#browser-new-page-option-record-video).

Don't forget to call `browserContext.close()` at the end of your tests, for the videos to be successfully saved. Personally, I do it in `test.afterAll()` hook.

**EDIT**: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9002) regarding some config options not working as expected, including the `video` one. On the first comment, one of the developers states that *"*Video does not work in this case, that's a known issue.*"*. Maybe you can skip the `video` option completely - I guess it will still work.

**EDIT2**: To attach the video recording to Allure reporter, include the following code in `test.afterAll()` hook:

```
test.afterAll(async ({ }, testInfo) => {
  await context.close() // Required for successful save of video recording.
  const path = await page.video().path()
  await testInfo.attach('video', {
    path,
    contentType: 'video/webm',
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, by that way video is recording, but it still is not visible on Allure page, have found an answer that example: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14164#issuecomment-1126795890  is working and as you can see on allure that videos are present, but not in my case, don't you know why is it happening ?

Answer (score -1):

for playwright with allure report

```
After(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { result, pickle }: ITestCaseHookParameter) { 
   ...
   await this.page?.close();
   await this.context?.close();
   ...
   const buffer = fs.readFileSync(videoPath);
   await this.attach(buffer, 'video/webm'); 
});
```

video will be attached, it is shown as a link `attachment`, when click on it - open in the next tab video with scenario run
[image]